# How to add a data-testid to a table row in antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I would like to add a custom `data-testid` to a *row* in an antd table, but from the [docs](https://ant.design/components/table/) I don't see how you can hook into annotating the table *row* itself. Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, you can use the `rowClassName` property of the table to add a class to that particular row:

```
  const classNameGenerator = (record, index) => {
    if(record.id == 2) {
      return "my-special-row";
    }
    return "";
  };

<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} rowClassName={classNameGenerator} />
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
      <Table
          onRow={(record, rowIndex) => ({
            'data-test-id': `here data test id`,
            id: `here id`,
          })}
```